# How to properly type app state in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'Todo[]'.
 20 |   return (
 21 |     <Wrapper>
 22 |       {store?.todos?.map((item) => (
    |               ^
```

This is my component:

```
const TodoList: React.FC = () => {
  const todoSelector = (state: ApplicationState) => state.todos;
  const store = useSelector(todoSelector);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {store?.todos?.map((item) => (
        <Todolement key={item.id} element={item}>
          {item.name} {item.content}
        </TodoElement>
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

My application state:

```
export interface ApplicationState {
  todos: Todo[];
}
```

And todo type:

```
export type Todo = {
  id: string;
  content: string;
  name: string;
};
```

How to properly type this state to avoid this issue?

**====================== update ======================**

I added `console.log(store)` in list component and it returns:
`{todos: Array(0)}`

My initial state in store: `{ todos: [] }`

**===================== update 2 =====================**

My store init:

```
const composedEnhancers = composeWithDevTools();
const initialState = getState();

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);
```

`getState` method:

```
const getState = (): any => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('todos');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return { todos: [] };
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

Root reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  todos: todoReducer,
});
```

And todo reducer:

```
export type TodoAction = ActionType<typeof actions>;

export type TodoState = Readonly<{
  todos: Todo[];
}>;

const initialState: TodoState = {
  todos: [],
};

export default combineReducers<TodoState, TodoAction>({
  todos: (state = initialState.todos, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ADD_TODO:
        return [...state, action.payload];
```

Comment: where did the error come from

Comment: @arslan2012 it comes from `{store?.todos?.map((item) => `

Comment: if your returned value is `{todos: Array(0)}`, so you either provided the wrong info of your state or your selector to us (if selector, the correct one should be `({ todos: state.todos })`, if state, it should be nested in one level of `todos`)

Comment: My initial state in redux looks like this: `return { todos: [] }` - is it wrong?

Comment: I guess you are likely provide the wrong structure of your state. Can you show the code of the way you create store?

Comment: Sure, I added update

Comment: You missed to share the code how to create rootReducer?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I added all reducers

Comment: Did you check the answer yet?

Comment: Not yet, but I think it's the correct anwser. Using twice `combineReducers` is the obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your code above is that you nested the `todos` state by several levels by using function `combineReducers`.

Here is what I meant, in your `todoReducer` you `export` this:

```
export default combineReducers<TodoState, TodoAction>({
  todos: (state = initialState.todos, action) => {

// Redux will wrap your state in `todos` key this way
```

And at your `rootReducer`, you combine them once again:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  todos: todoReducer,
});
```

which means your `todos` state is now nested 2 levels of `todos` which is not as same as the state you has expressed in your type `ApplicationState`, here is the actual store:

```
{
  todos: {
    todos: []
  }
}
```

In order to keep the state align with `ApplicationState`, you just simply don't have to use `combineReducers` and don't initialize with object has `todos` key in your `todoReducer`:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
 // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your interface and selector, your `store` is a todo array, not an application object

```
const TodoList: React.FC = () => {   const todoSelector = (state: ApplicationState) => state.todos;   const store = useSelector(todoSelector);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {store.map((item) => (
        <Todolement key={item.id} element={item}>
          {item.name} {item.content}
        </TodoElement>
      ))}
    </Wrapper>   ); };
```

Comment: It returns `TypeError: store.map is not a function`

Comment: need to check what is your store

Comment: My initial store: `{ todos: [] }`